# Why is my code exiting out before method completion for this scenario?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, async-await, asp.net-web-api2

I have a console app which calls methods like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Test();
}

static async void Test()
{
    await SyncADToDBAsync();
}

static async Task SyncADToDBAsync()
{
    using (var client = GetHttpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            var action = new { Type = "SyncADToDB",
                Domains = new string[] { "my.domain" } };
            var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(
                "api/v1/active-directory/actions", action);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var x = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

However, the console app exits out when I step into the line of code with `client.PostAsJsonAsync()`. How can I structure the code so the console app doesn't exit, so the console app waits for the value returned by the service? It looks like the target Web API controller method isn't getting hit by the test call either although the service method was getting hit earlier when I implemented the call using `WebClient` instead of `HttpClient`.

Comment: You're not awaiting. You need to await up the chain.

Comment: You aren’t waiting for Test to complete. Either make Main also async or if you are using an older .NET do `TestAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. That being said, don’t ever use `async avoid` - that’s reserved for event handlers.

Answer (score 2):

> [W]hy is my code exiting out before method completion for this scenario?

The code is exiting because although `SyncADToDBAsync` is waiting for `PostAsJsonAsync` to complete, and `Test` is waiting for `SyncADToDBAsync` to complete, `Main` is not waiting for `Test` to complete and is thereby exiting too soon.

> How can I structure the code so the console app doesn't exit, so the console app waits for the value returned by the service?

We need to tell `Main` to wait for `Test` to complete. We also need `Test` to return a `Task` instead of `void`, because we can await a `Task` but we cannot await `void`.

This is probably close to the structure that you are needing:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // use GetAwaiter().GetResult() to prevent
        // the program from exiting until after
        // the async task(s) have completed.
        Test().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    static async Task Test()
    {
        await SyncADToDBAsync();
    }

    static async Task SyncADToDBAsync()
    {
        // for the sake of this example,
        // we are using Task.Delay(ms) to
        // emulate the non-blocking call to the HttpClient
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Do something with the response.");
    }
}
```

Here it is [as a Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Aj7ewy). And here is [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/59) that refers to using `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.

Comment: Quick heads-up, C# 7.1 introduces [Async Main Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-1#async-main).